# The table does not refresh to store a new record in database with VuejJs and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a form which it stores records to a database ... this form is just one input like this one:

This is in the route create/deposit

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" 
  v-model="form.deposit_number" placeholder="Enter the deposit number" required>
</div>
```

This is in the route create/deposit
I use this VueJs code to store the record:

```
onSubmit(e) {  
   e.preventDefault();
   let currentObj = this;

   const config = {
     headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
   }

   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('deposit_number', this.form.deposit_number);

   axios.post('/api/deposit/store?api_token='+App.apiToken, formData, config)
            .then(function (response) {
                currentObj.success = response.data.success;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

    this.$refs.createDeposit.reset(); // This will clear that form

    this.$awn.success("El registro ha sido agregado", {labels: {success: "Éxito"}});

    this.$router.push('/deposit');
 }
```

How you can see I store and then I redirect to deposit component, I have a table which it displays the stored database records like this one:

This is in the route deposit

```
  <table v-if="total > 0" class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
       <tr>
         <th>Number</th>
       </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(post, index) in posts" v-bind:index="index">
        <td>{{ post.deposit_id }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

But I have a problem because when I add a new record it does not refresh the table to show that new one.. so I have to click in another component and get back and then I can see the new record what I try to say it's that it does not refresh automaticly when I add a new record so I wonder how can I refresh the table? because If I add a new one I need that it displays automaticly when I am redirected to deposit component.

Thanks.

Comment: `this.$router.push('/deposit');` where does this lead to? Is this the same route as the one which contains the add record form?

Comment: @tamrat no the form it's in the route create/deposit